# angularjs ngGrid checkbox not updating model

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a checkbox column inside an ngGrid. Checking or unchecking the checkbos does not seem to update the object bound to the row. How can i achive the model update on the change of the checkbox value
any help is much appretiated

thanks
Ben

Comment: You're going to need to show some code, preferably in a plunker or fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

With ng-grid you can use the afterSelectionChange method in the grid definition. I have some example code that highlights how to use the functionality at http://plnkr.co/edit/nULoI4.

Answer (score 0):

The attached entity is reflecting the changes after setting ng-model on the checkbox.